# MySQL not starting because "mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)"

Tags: mysql

I am setting up a new LAMP server with Ubuntu Server 13.10 and MySQL 5.5 and was in the middle of migrating mysql databases to new server when I realized mysql server is not running. All was fine last time I checked a couple of days ago. I get this when I try to launch server from command line:

```
@Ubuntu:~$ sudo mysqld start
[sudo] password for XXX:
140402 10:32:07 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140402 10:32:07 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140402 10:32:07 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
140402 10:32:07 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
140402 10:32:07 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140402 10:32:07 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140402 10:32:07 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140402 10:32:07 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140402 10:32:07 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140402 10:32:07 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140402 10:32:07 InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Also when I try this:

```
XXX@Ubuntu-SHS:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld [ OK ]
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld [fail]
```

Nothing at all in error logs.
Update: Noticed that all Directories & files under `/var/lib/mysql` have been changed to messagebus for owner/group. is this right? My other setup shows everything as `mysql mysql`.

Comment: Your question has been [asked](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56441) previously on [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com) and you may find useful [its asnwer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56442). Let us know if that is a working solution. Just to mention, `140402` is not the error number but your system date.